# Чтение не связанных данных в entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Как на примере двух таблиц не связанных между собой зная id ключа строки первой таблицы (Vehicle) получить данные со второй таблицы (repair)? Во второй таблице id не является ключом, обычное int поле.
Например, есть страница представления Details таблицы Vehicle, выводит детальную информацию и все связанные данные с других таблиц, но как ее заставить найти все записи с (int? id) в таблице repair и вывести все это в одном представлении? Это возможно? Какие есть варианты реализации? Заранее благодарю!

Контроллер

```
`public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Vehicle vehicle = db.Vehicle.Find(id);
            if (vehicle == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(vehicle);
        }`
```

Модель

```
public class Repair
{
    [Key]
    public int RepairID { get; set; }

    ..
    
    public int Vehicle_id { get; set; } //  в этом поле хранится id Vehicle

    public string Record { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }


public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    ..
}
```

Comment: Сделайте внешним ключом, самому же будет потом проще жить. Самый очевидный вариант - использовать `.Include()` при выборке, раз у вас linq.

Comment: Дело в том в VehicleID может оказаться очень много id  с разных таблиц и чтобы не создавать много таблиц и связок хотелось попробовать сделать именно так. Уже очень любопытно понять саму реализацию.

Comment: А что тут думать? В чистом sql вы можете указать в join'е указать связку в ON, в linq не сможете. Будете читать разными запросами - упадёт производительность в столько раз сколько читаете строк. Структура ваша неканоническая и граблей соберёте достаточно. Классический способ - внешний ключ и разные таблицы. Вы просто подумайте о том, насколько хорошо будет работать индекс по столбцу еслиданных в ней - две таблицы по миллиону строк (пять таблиц, десять) а вам нужно читать только данные из одной таблицы. Может сразу себе FULL SCAN устроить, а потом бегать с проблемами производительности? )

Comment: Я Вас понял. Спасибо большое!